# What's the difference between seq.nth and seq.item?

Tags: f#

Looking at the MSDN docs for [Seq.nth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.nth%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) and [Seq.item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.item%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), they appear to do exactly the same thing. Both have the same description... *Computes the nth element in the collection*

What's the difference? If there isn't one, why have both?

Comment: I believe nth is deprecated. You can use item with arrays, lists, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `nth` is deprecated is because the type signature for `Seq.nth` and `List.nth` is different, and [so `nth` was deprecated in favor of `item`](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md) to avoid confusion. (Search for the word "nth" in that document to find the discussion). There was apparently also an `Array.nth` function at some point, but it no longer appears in the F# documentation on MSDN so I can't tell you what its signature was.

[Signature for `Seq.nth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.nth%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
Seq.nth : int -> seq<'T> -> 'T
```

[Signature for `List.nth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.nth%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
List.nth : 'T list -> int -> 'T
```

Note that the way `List.nth` is defined, you can't do `someList |> List.nth 5`. The `Seq.nth` takes its parameters in the correct order so that `someSeq |> Seq.nth 5` is possible, but having these two functions take their parameters in a different order leads to confusion. To avoid this confusion, `nth` was deprecated and replaced by `item`, which has the same signature for lists, seqs, and arrays. (Yes, `someArray |> Array.item 5` is possible, even though you'd usually just write that as `someArray.[5]`).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the background. So I should use Seq.item then?

Comment: Yes, use `Seq.item` rather than `Seq.nth`. Just be aware that it has to count from the beginning to find the item, so it's O(N). If you're calling it repeatedly to fetch various items from the seq, then you should convert it to an array — which has O(1) lookup — first.

Comment: Thanks, all makes sense

Answer (score 3):

You can check the source code of these functions here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs

```
[<CompiledName("Get")>]
let nth index (source : seq<'T>) = item index source
```

So they are the same.

Comment: Functions, not methods.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'm accepting @rmunn's answer, even though yours came in first, as his explained the background. Hope that's OK.